# ExpressionEngine, Create a front-end dropdown list from backend Multi Select custom field

Tags: drop-down-menu, expressionengine, multi-select

Evening all,

I have a Multi-Select custom field in my ExpressionEngine backend which I need to create a drop-down list from in my EE site.  I can't think of a way but I'm sure it can't be too difficult. Can anyone explain how to do this please? (Preferably without the purchase of a plugin etc..)

Many thanks in advance

Comment: What version of EE are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using EE2 and the native [Multi-Select Field](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/modules/channel/custom_fields.html#multiselect_fields) custom channel field, this code will output all *selected* options from your multi-select custom field:

```
<select>
    {exp:channel:entries channel="channel_name" limit="1" dynamic="off"}
        {custom_field_name}
            <option value="{item}">{item}</option>
        {/custom_field_name}
    {/exp:channel:entries}
</select>
```

The syntax for outputting the contents of a Multi-Select custom field in EE2 is slightly different from EE1. Instead of using `{option}` to output the value, it's been replaced with `{item}`.

Also of interest is that the native, "built-in" Multi-Select custom field in EE2 can't output an *option* and *value* separately.

You can use the [P&T Field Pack](http://pixelandtonic.com/divebar) to restore the EE1 FF Multi-select functionality where a Multi-Select custom field can have a value **and** an option.

Comment: That's fantastic Ryan! Thanks very much for your help x

Answer (score 0):

Not even a $5 plugin?

http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/custom-drop-down/

Comment: Thanks, that looks like what I am looking for. It's not a cost issue. I live in Indonesia and unfortunately it's very difficult for a foreign person to have an Indonesian bank account that can be used to purchase things online :-(

Answer (score 0):

What Multi-Select custom fieldtype and version of ExpressionEngine are you using?

If you're using [FF Multi-select](http://pixelandtonic.com/fieldframe) on [EE1](http://expressionengine.com/legacy_docs/), this code will output *all options* from your multi-select custom field:

```
<select>
    {exp:weblog:entries weblog="weblog_name" limit="1" dynamic="off"}
        {custom_field_name:all_options}
            <option value="{option_name}">{option}</option>
        {/custom_field_name:all_options}
    {/exp:weblog:entries}
</select>
```

If you only want to output the *selected options* in the multi-select custom field, this code will output them for you:

```
<select>
    {exp:weblog:entries weblog="weblog_name" limit="1" dynamic="off"}
        {custom_field_name}
            <option value="{option_name}">{option}</option>
        {/custom_field_name}
    {/exp:weblog:entries}
</select>
```

If you're using EE2, the code will need to be updated since EllisLab renamed *weblogs* to *channels* and changed {option} and {option_name} to the combined variable {item}.

Comment: Hi Ryan,  Thank you very much for your help. Sorry for the delay in my response.  Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work.  I'm using EE 2.1.3 and the Multi Select custom field type.  Let me show you the code I'm using following your advice:

Comment: `<select>
    {exp:channel:entries channel="fashion" limit="1" dynamic="off"}
        {fashion-available-sizes}
            <option value="{option_name}">{option}</option>
        {/fashion-available-sizes}
    {/exp:channel:entries}
</select>`

Comment: oops, seems I don't know how to post code, even with the instructions below, sorry

Comment: I've rewritten the code for EE2 and submitted it as a new answer. If it addresses your question, please vote it up and/or accept it as the answer. Thanks!